# What is the Triskelion supposed to do?

Tags: little-witch-academia

In Little Witch Academia series, Ursula is attempting to make Akko say all the ***Seven Words of Arcturus*** that supposedly would reawaken the Triskelion.

What is the Triskelion, and what does it do?

Answer (score 2):

In Episode 15, it's explained that the Triskelion contains the "last vestiges" of Yggdrasil, the Great Tree, whose roots once covered the world and allowed magic to flourish. These vestiges contain "world-altering magic", allowing whoever wields them to change the world around them as they see fit, so long as they have the Shiny Rod and have awakened all seven Words.

Ursula's plan is to use this world-altering magic to reverse the worldwide magical decline and usher in a new Golden Age of Magic. In the final episode,

> Akko succeeds in doing so with help from Diana and her friends, reviving Yggdrasil in the process.

Answer (score 1):

My theory on what might the Triskellion be starts with the opening. The opening starts off with Akko, Lotte and Sucy holding hands leading to spiral formation to the Seven Words of Arcturus till finally a tree which I call Yggdrasil, the world tree.  In mythology, Yggdrasil was this very powerful and ancient tree that held the nine realms of the Norse Mythology. As you probably read, think about this, nine worlds and the Nine Olde Witches. Probably the Nine Olde Witches and Little Witch Academia as a world has influence of the Norse.

The ‘ready for battle’ sequence. All of Akko’s friends, her teammates, Amanda and her team, Diana and Akko herself but before I talked about Akko, I want to talk about the ley lines. If you look closer, the ley lines had what looked to be branches or roots which connects to Yggdrasil. Why is that? Well, the answer is that what we are looking at are the roots of the world tree itself. The Ley lines are the Roots of the World Tree, Yggdrasil. So, all that meant is that all the Witches and the Faeries are taking in this magical energy from one of the most ancient forces in the universe. Also, could this mean the world where Akko is having her adventures is located at one of the nine realms. However, this presents a case on what’s happening to Yggdrasil.

We understand that magic came from somewhere, probably Yggdrasil but at some point, the magic is getting less which foretells a frightening conclusion, the world tree is dying. If that happens, all the worlds including Earth would be destroyed without Yggdrasil holding them together. That might be the purpose of Chariot. By reviving the Seven Words of Arcturus, they can revive Yggdrasil who will in turn support the worlds once more.

Therefore, the Grand Triskellion might be a new seed to give birth to a new Yggdrasil.